# How to count only certain colours in an image

Tags: javascript

I learning javascript and I thought it would be interesting to make an app that counts tree rings. So I am trying to make a javascript app that counts tree rings to give you an estimate of the age of the tree. I can count how many colours there are between two points on the image, but I want to only count the rings not every colour. I think I need to make an algorithm that only increments a count when the colour goes from a light shade of a colour to a dark shade of a colour. The problem is I have no idea how to do this. So can anyone help me to do this or point me in the right direction?
Thanks, the code is below.

```js
var $picked = $("#picked"); // Just to preview picked colors
var canvas = $('#canvas_picker')[0];
var startX, startY;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
var colorList = []; //This will hold all our colors 
var colors = 0;
var colorsRequired = ['#AB8771', '#D9C4AF', '#ECCEB4', '#B27D55', '#CAA289']; //['#E5CAAF','#C19D83','#F4D6BA','##E7C6A5','#D7BEAA','#E6BEA4','#BB7A52'];
$("#file_upload").change(function(e) {
  var F = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
  reader.readAsDataURL(F);
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = this.width; // If needed? adjust canvas size
    canvas.height = this.height; // respective to image size
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // Draw image at 0, 0, not at 10, 10
  };
  img.src = e.target.result;
}

//To get all colors from Image ADDED
function getColors(x, y, xx, yy) {
  var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, xx, yy);
  var data = imageData.data;

  // quickly iterate over all pixels
  for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 50) {
    var r = data[i];
    var g = data[i + 1];
    var b = data[i + 2];
    //If you need the alpha value it's data[i + 3]
    var hex = rgbToHex(r + g + b);
    if (($.inArray(hex, colorList) == -1) && ($.inArray(hex, colorsRequired) == -1) && colorList.length < 10000) {
      colorList.push(hex);
    }
  }
  return colorList.length;
}
////// END //////

// To get color from Image
$('#canvas_picker').click(function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left; // Fixed coordinates
  var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top; // respective to canvas offs.
  var img_data = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
  var R = img_data[0];
  var G = img_data[1];
  var B = img_data[2];
  var rgb = R + ',' + G + ',' + B;
  var hex = rgbToHex(R, G, B);
  $('#rgb input').val(rgb);
  $('#hex input').val('#' + hex);
  $picked.append("<span style='background:#" + hex + "'>#" + hex + "</span>");
});

function rgbToHex(R, G, B) {
  return toHex(R) + toHex(G) + toHex(B);
}

function toHex(n) {
  n = parseInt(n, 10);
  if (isNaN(n)) return "00";
  n = Math.max(0, Math.min(n, 255));
  return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n - n % 16) / 16) + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n % 16);
}
//////Ends /////////////////////

//To redraw Image  
function drawTheImage(img) { //ADDED
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var imageDpi = 300;
  var can = document.getElementById('canvas_picker'); // CORRECTED
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

  $("canvas").mousedown(function(event) {
    startX = event.pageX;
    startY = event.pageY;

    $(this).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
      drawLine(startX, startY, e.pageX, e.pageY);
    });
  }).mouseup(function() {
    $(this).unbind('mousemove');
  });

  function drawLine(x, y, stopX, stopY) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
    drawTheImage(img); // ADDED
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(stopX, stopY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    colorList = [];
    colors = getColors(x, y, stopX, stopY);
    document.getElementById('colors').innerText = colors;
    // calculate length   
    var pixelLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((stopX - x), 2) + Math.pow((stopY - y), 2));
    var physicalLength = pixelLength / imageDpi;
    console.log("line length = " + physicalLength +
      " inches (image at " + imageDpi + " dpi)", colors);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #ddd;
}

#picked span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  font: 8px/50px Arial;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<canvas width="600" height="300" id="canvas_picker"></canvas><br>
<input type="file" id="file_upload"><br>
<div id="hex">HEX: <input type="text"></div>
<div id="rgb">RGB: <input type="text"></div>

<div id="picked"></div>
No. of Colors:
<div id="colors"></div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've picked a tough task for learning, that's for sure.

Probably the easiest way would be to:

1. convert your colors to scalar grayscale values one way or another,
   be it `(R+G+B)/3` or L from [HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (likely will work better);
2. find a threshold value (may be automated for each image by just
   averaging the colors);
3. then finally scan the image radially from edges to center and count how many times it crosses the threshold both ways (a single line of pixels half the image width).

This approach assumes you have your image of rings cropped & centered, otherwise you'd need a more complicated solution, probably involving something along the lines of [CV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision).